# app with large raw text file would not run on android phone

Tags: android, file

I have developed a word app (Hangman) for android. The app uses a raw word text file of over 100,000 words. The app runs nicely on the Android emulator on  my laptop. I don't have an Android phone myself to test it but my niece does. So I made the apk file and emailed to her and apparently the app would not run on her phone. I sent her again the same app again with only a few words in the text file and it ran nicely. Why do you think it would not run with the larger word file?

Comment: What kind of phone does your niece have? Is it by any chance a Galaxy S phone?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this before. Some phones don't allow you to have assets larger than 1MB. I think this has something to do with compression and AssetManager. As far as I see there are two solutions.

1) Split your asset into pieces smaller than 1MB and glue them together at runtime. This is what I did since I didn't have the time for 2).

2) Figure out how to properly and portably store larger assets:)